# Static routing in Linux

Tags: routing, linux

I want to know how static routes are evaluated in Linux. Have a few more specific questions.

1. How are metrics used?
2. If the packet is the last hop what do I put in the next hop field of the route? For example, if the packet is going to 192.168.1.2 should the router at .1 have a next hop of 192.168.1.1?
3. What order are the routes applied?

Any explanation or external links are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but linux questions are not a good fit for this site... have you considered [su], [sf], [ask-ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: For what it's worth, questions shouldn't be dismissed out of hand simply because they're Linux-based, as it's increasingly used in serious and complex routing scenarios. (That said, this particular question is for Google.)

Comment: @chrylis, The question isn't dismissed because it's linux-based.  I have been a rabid linux user for over 15 years; however, there are already four other sites that handle linux questions, including [sf]... we don't need to continue muddling the water over where to find linux solutions.

Comment: I was only referring to your phrasing. Linux questions should be a good fit for this site if they deal with actual network-engineering issues (e.g., having a Linux VM that serves as an IPv6 tunnel terminator and speaks OSPFv3). "How do I install Quagga?" should go on Server Fault, but "Why is Quagga getting stuck in EXSTART?" probably goes here.

Comment: @chrylis, [quagga very clearly looks on-topic on SF](http://serverfault.com/search?q=quagga)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Metrics show preference over another route with same prefix. For example you can  assign a low metric on a fast interface and a higher metric on a slow interface. If the fast interface goes down for some reason the slow interface will be used.

2) Next hop is the gateway for this route. If your device is 192.168.1.100/24 and you want to add a static route for 10.0.0.0/8 with the gateway being 192.168.1.1, this is going to be your next hop.

3) There is no special order. After you enter all the routes you want they will be used depending on the closest match, e.g 10.0.0.1/32 is preferred over 10.0.0.0/24, or the metric.